# how to prevent a single MDI child form stealing focus from every other mdi child form

Tags: c#, winforms, mdichild

There are several MDI child form within my window,
one of MDI child form after it's being launched will 
cause the focus mechanism to be weird, meaning a another MDI child window
will not get the focus unless the title bar is clicked, clicking 
anywhere else in the mdi child form will not caused the form to focus.

any thoughts?

Comment: There several custom control embedded within the mdi child control (custom controls such as a calendar /schedule like controls, which involves a lot of mouse click/operation handlers)

is there a way to find out what the default mouseclick behavior is?

Comment: also, for some reason sometimes the "font" settings can also messed up the focus of a form, any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put this as a comment if I had enough rep since it's only a guess because there isn't a lot of information in the question.

Try making sure that the MDI children are handling the click event to make sure that focus is being set to the form that is being clicked on. I haven't ever really noticed behavior like this the only think of is you are somehow overriding the default mouseclick behavior on the other MDI children that are being populated, but since I don't think you can override the title bar click I think this is why it still works.

Could explain what you're doing inside of the MDI child a little so we can get a better understanding of what is going on that could be causing this behavior.

Comment: thanks for the comment, at least it's a start and i think it's the right direction.

Comment: Yea, sorry I couldn't be more specific it's hard to tell sometimes when you don't know exactly what is going on with the control.